# implementing minimax algorithm but AI loses sometimes

Tags: c

`fairly new to c and i just created a perfect minimax algorithm tic tac toe. How do i improve it such that it becomes imperfect (meaning it might not make the best possible moves all the time)

I've researched online and I know it has something to do with depth but I have no idea how to implement depth into my code.

this is my code

```
char gridChar(int i) {
    switch(i) {
        case -1:
            return 'X';
        case 0:
            return ' ';
        case 1:
            return 'O';
    }
}

void draw(int b[9]) {
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n",gridChar(b[0]),gridChar(b[1]),gridChar(b[2]));
    printf("---+---+---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n",gridChar(b[3]),gridChar(b[4]),gridChar(b[5]));
    printf("---+---+---\n");
    printf(" %c | %c | %c\n",gridChar(b[6]),gridChar(b[7]),gridChar(b[8]));
}

int win(const int board[9]) {
    //determines if a player has won, returns 0 otherwise.
    unsigned wins[8][3] = {{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{0,3,6},{1,4,7},{2,5,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if(board[wins[i][0]] != 0 &&
           board[wins[i][0]] == board[wins[i][1]] &&
           board[wins[i][0]] == board[wins[i][2]])
            return board[wins[i][2]];
    }
    return 0;
}

int minimax(int board[9], int player, int depth) {
    //How is the position like for player (their turn) on board?
    int winner = win(board);
    int move;
    if(winner != 0) return winner*player;

    move = -1;
    int score = -2;//Losing moves are preferred to no move
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {//For all moves,
        if(board[i] == 0) {//If legal,
            board[i] = player;//Try the move
            int thisScore = -minimax(board, player*-1, ++depth);
            if(thisScore > score) {
                score = thisScore;
                move = i;
            }//Pick the one that's worst for the opponent
            board[i] = 0;//Reset board after try
        }
    }
    if(move == -1) return 0;
    return score;
}

void computerMove(int board[9]) {
    int move = -1;
    int score = -2;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
        if(board[i] == 0) {
            board[i] = 1;
            int tempScore = -minimax(board, -1, -1);
            board[i] = 0;
            if(tempScore > score) {
                score = tempScore;
                move = i;
            }
        }
    }
    //returns a score based on minimax tree at a given node.
    board[move] = 1;
}

void playerMove(int board[9]) {
    int move = 0;
    do {
        printf("\nInput move ([0..8]): ");
        scanf("%d", &move);
        printf("\n");
    } while (move >= 9 || move < 0 || board[move] != 0);
    board[move] = -1;
}

int main() {
    int board[9] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    //computer squares are 1, player squares are -1.
    printf("Computer: O, You: X\nPlay (1)st or (2)nd? ");
    int player=0;
    scanf("%d",&player);
    printf("\n");
    unsigned turn;
    for(turn = 0; turn < 9 && win(board) == 0; ++turn) {
        if((turn+player) % 2 == 0)
            computerMove(board);
        else {
            draw(board);
            playerMove(board);
        }
    }
    switch(win(board)) {
        case 0:
            printf("A draw. How droll.\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            draw(board);
            printf("You lose.\n");
            break;
        case -1:
            printf("You win. Inconceivable!\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

edit: I tried making changes to my minimax function by adding depth but i'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: You could randomly choose a sub-optimal move at any point.  Say you give it an 80% probability of using the optimal move and therefore a 20% probability of any other valid move.  You might or might not decide to calculate the optimal move before applying the randomization.  If you do calculate the optimal move, you can ensure you don't take that move when choosing a possible move at random.  If you don't know the optimal move, you might select it at random anyway.  Either way works.  Clearly, if there's only one move left, you have to use it.

Comment: _"I have no idea how to implement depth"_ - but it seems you have  already? `int minimax(int board[9], int player, int depth)`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hi thanks for the response. I only just added in the parameter but I have no idea on how to use it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for responding. Do you mean I have to create another function e.g bestOptimalMove to find the best move for the AI then give it a probability?

Comment: You should use it to abort the recursion when you reach a certain depth. The deeper you let it search, the better the computer player will be

Comment: Jonathan Leffler's suggestion is really good, but instead of choosing not to select the optimal move you might instead randomly choose not to evaluate a move at all (i.e. delete it from the set of possible moves)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Do u have any examples that i can look at?

Comment: Sure, look at the pseudo-code at wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax

Comment: @Tibrogargan meaning i have to create another function e.g leastOptimalMove and not evaluate the board and randomly place X at any postition?

Comment: Not quite.  When a turn needs to be calculated there are going to be 1 or more possible selections that could be made.  If there's more than one, simply randomly decide to not evaluate one of the possible moves, and then select the best move from the ones you have remaining.  Sometimes a good move won't be evaluated, sometimes a bad move won't be evaluated.  This simulates a person not perceiving a move.

Comment: @Tibrogargan hmm do you have any code examples that I can reference to? Or could you show me how I can implement it into my code?

Comment: In `minimax`, after you test if a move is legal (`if(board[i] == 0) {//If legal,`).  Instead of immediately trying the move skip it randomly:  `if (Math.random() > 0.8) { continue )`.  You will probably only want to do this once a game, so maybe add a flag.

Comment: @Tibrogargan so what this does is skip my remaining codes below? Also Math.random is not in C code right?

Comment: @Tibrogargan also what kind of flag should I put such that it runs only once per game?

Comment: [Previous version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74189056).